# how to modify value of product_price forcefully using function tag in odoo 11?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, function, decimal, odoo-11

I want to change product price =4 how to do by code? this file is product_data in product module.

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="decimal_price" model="decimal.precision">
        <field name="name">Product Price</field>
        <field name="digits">2</field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
<!--   Edit Data Record [decimal_price]   -->
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'decimal_price')]"/>
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': False}"/>
</function>

<record forcecreate="True" id="product.decimal_price" model="decimal.precision">
    <field name="name">Product Price</field>
    <field name="digits">4</field>
</record>

<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('module', '=', 'product'), ('name', '=', 'decimal_price')]"/>
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': True}"/>
</function>
```